# How can one improve downvoted content?

Tags: feature-request, voting

For improving the quality of content downvoting is useless *if the downvoter does not tell what is wrong with the question or answer.*

How can I improve my content if I don't know what is wrong?

Uncommented downvotes feel like attacks on my person, they are not helping me or the community to produce better content.

Wouldn't it be better to allow downvoting only with detailed corrections and/or improvement suggestions?